# data-parent attribute not working on collapse bootstrap v4-alpha

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to close first collapsible element after I click on second but it's not working.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="advancedOptions">
      <p class="advanced-search-options ml-1">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#advancedOptions" href="#advancedSearchOptions" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="advancedSearchOptions">Advanced search options</a>
        or browse by
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#advancedOptions" href="#areaList" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="areaList">area list</a>
      </p>

      <div class="collapse" id="advancedSearchOptions" aria-labelledby="advancedSearchOptions">
        Advanced Search Options
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="areaList" aria-labelledby="areaList">
        Area List
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lppf5r2z/

Comment: You want to build kind of accordian panel?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Check  https://jsfiddle.net/Lppf5r2z/ it should work like an accordion.

Comment: Accordion basically is done with **[this way](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example)** AFAIK. So with the current implementation, I suspect you might need some jquery code written to achieve this. Would you mind if you get it done with jquery?

Comment: No problem with jquery, just want to get it done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a click event to your `a[role="tab"]` where in you just need to hide all the open `collapse`.

```
$('a[role="tab"]').on('click',function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lppf5r2z/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this code.

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="advancedOptions">
      <p class="advanced-search-options ml-1">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#advancedOptions" href="#advancedSearchOptions" class="link-data" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="areaList">Advanced search options</a>
        or browse by
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#advancedOptions" href="#areaList" class="link-data" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="advancedSearchOptions">area list</a>
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#advancedOptions" href="#areaList1" class="link-data" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="advancedSearchOptions">area list 1</a>
      </p>

      <div class="collapse div-custom" id="advancedSearchOptions" aria-labelledby="advancedSearchOptions">
        Advanced Search Options
      </div>
      <div class="collapse div-custom" id="areaList" aria-labelledby="areaList">
        Area List
      </div>
      <div class="collapse div-custom" id="areaList1" aria-labelledby="areaList">
        Area List 123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var hide_id = "";
        $(".link-data").click(function () {
            if(hide_id != null && hide_id != ''){
                $(hide_id).hide('slow');
            }
            hide_id = $(this).attr("href");
        });
    });
```

Or you can you do via this code.

```
$(".link-data").click(function () {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

In this html code you just need to add **class="link-data"**

```
<a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#advancedOptions" href="#advancedSearchOptions" class="link-data" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="areaList">Advanced search options</a>
```

Last option is better then first one.